# Rendering in a small section of my window

Tags: c, rendering, sdl

I am currently working with **SDL2**. I am on **Mac OS** and I'm using **xCode**.
I have created a function to draw lines using randomly generated points. 
However, when I try to render the lines, they are only render in a subset of my window (top left square).

Here's my code.

**main.c**

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include "utils.h"


#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480

// Prototypes
void drawRandomPoints( int pointsNo, SDL_Renderer *renderer );
void drawRandomLines( int linesNo, SDL_Renderer *renderer );


int main( int argc, const char * argv[] ) {

    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow( "Hello World", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL );

    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC );

    int running = 1;
    SDL_Event event;
    while( running ) {

        while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) ) {

            if( event.type == SDL_QUIT ) {

                running = 0;

            }

        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255 );
        SDL_RenderClear( renderer );

        // Draw a point
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255 );
        drawRandomLines( 100, renderer );


        SDL_RenderPresent( renderer );

    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer( renderer );
    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );


    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;

}

void drawRandomPoints( int pointsNo, SDL_Renderer *renderer ) {

    int i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < pointsNo; ++i ) {

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, getRandomColor(), getRandomColor(), getRandomColor(), 255 );
        SDL_RenderDrawPoint( renderer, getRandomNumber( 0, SCREEN_WIDTH ), getRandomNumber( 0, SCREEN_HEIGHT ) );

    }


}

void drawRandomLines( int linesNo, SDL_Renderer *renderer ) {

    int i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < linesNo; ++i ) {

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, getRandomColor(), getRandomColor(), getRandomColor(), 255 );

        SDL_RenderDrawLine( renderer, getRandomNumber( 0, SCREEN_WIDTH ), getRandomNumber( 0, SCREEN_HEIGHT ), getRandomNumber( 0, SCREEN_WIDTH ), getRandomNumber( 0, SCREEN_HEIGHT ) );

    }

}
```

**utils.c**

```
#include "utils.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int getRandomNumber( int min, int max ) {

    static int init = 0;

    if( !init ) {

        srand( time( NULL ) );
        init = 1;

    }

    return ( rand() % ( max - min + 1 ) ) + min;

}

int getRandomColor() {

    return getRandomNumber( 0, 255 );

}
```

Here's the result when compiling.
[SDL window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rra6U.png)

Comment: You're only using VGA (640x480) and I would bet your display settings are much larger than that...  Try using SDL_GetWindowSize(...) to pick your random numbers from.

Comment: I've found this function SDL_GL_GetDrawableSize but I'm not sure how to use it since its a void return type.

Comment: I suspect `SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI` is throwing you off.  What values does [`SDL_GetRendererOutputSize()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetRendererOutputSize) populate `w` and `h` with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only using a VGA size screen by defining these;

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480
```

Try this

```
int SCREEN_WIDTH=640;
int SCREEN_HEIGHT=480;
```

and add to main like this;

```
SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow( "Hello World", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL );
SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC );

SDL_GL_GetDrawableSize(window,&SCREEN_WIDTH,&SCREEN_HEIGHT);
```

Comment: @PierrePasquet Please accept the answer if it works for you.